# android gridview doesn't respond click event after back from other Activity

Tags: android, gridview

1.I set GridView OnItemClickListener at **MyFragment**

```
        noScrollgridview.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity());
        adapter.update();
        noScrollgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        noScrollgridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                if (arg2 == Bimp.SelectBitmap.size()) {
                    ll_popup.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getActivity(), R.anim.activity_translate_in));
                    pop.showAtLocation(mBaseView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            GalleryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", "1");
                    intent.putExtra("ID", arg2);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

2.I click the gridview item and into **GalleryActivity**. At GalleryActivity, I clcik the "Cancel" Button and go back to the MyFragment.

3.When I back MyFragment interface, I can't click the grid item again.

Comment: are you doing anything in onStart() or onResume() method in Activity that will override the setOnItemClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

```
 noScrollgridview.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.update();
    noScrollgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    noScrollgridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            if (arg2 == Bimp.SelectBitmap.size()) {
                ll_popup.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        getActivity(), R.anim.activity_translate_in));
                pop.showAtLocation(mBaseView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", "1");
                intent.putExtra("ID", String.Valueof(arg2));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```